# NLTK tree labels for NER

Tags: python, nltk

any idea where I can find the set of possible labels that NLTK give to the tree such as PERSON, ORGANIZATION etc? 
I have tried searching for it in the documentation but I can't seem to find it.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nltk-users/f04E5JlFbcU) they are:

- FACILITY
- GPE
- GSP
- LOCATION
- ORGANIZATION
- PERSON

Someone else notes that

> [i]f you are using the stanford NER classifiers, the labels will change depending on the model you are using, for more information
>       http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Models